# Changing Directory with Wildcard in Zsh Shell

Tags: shell, zsh, directory

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro to Catalina 10.15. The shell has switched from bash to zsh. With bash, if I typed "cd Doc*/Virt*" (without quotes) from my home directory, it would take me to:

/Users/username/Documents/Virtual Machines

Now, with zsh, when I type "cd Doc*/Virt*", I get this error:

cd: string not in pwd: Documents/Virtual Machines

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This also works in zsh. If you get this error message, it means that exactly two files match the wildcard pattern, so after the wildcard expansion you had something like `cd 'Documents/Virtual Machines' 'Documents/Virtual Machines Backup'` which means to change to the directory obtained by replacing `Documents/Virtual Machines` by `Documents/Virtual Machines Backup` in the current working directory. “String not in pwd” says that the current working directory doesn't contain `Documents/Virtual Machines`.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh, this works:

```
cd Doc*/Virt*/
```